# Pydantic - Upgrading object to another model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a NewUser model that is something that the end user inputs, I want to update the object to a UserInDB so that I can pass it to my db engine (DynamoDB, which expects a dict)

At the moment I'm calling `.dict` twice, which doesn't feel like the correct way to do it

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional
from uuid import uuid4
    
class NewUser(BaseModel):
    name: str
    email: str
    company_name: Optional[str]
    
class UserInDB(NewUser):
    hash: str = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    range = 'DATA'
    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.now)
    
#...
#Emulating what an end user would send
user = NewUser(name='Example', company_name='example', email='example@example.com')
    
#Is calling dict twice way to do it?
user_in_db = UserInDB(**user.dict()).dict()
db.create_user(user_in_db)
```

Comment: IMHO, there is nothing wrong in calling the `.dict()` twice, you really need that.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to define an `__init__` and the code would look nicer (to me at least).

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional
from uuid import uuid4

class NewUser(BaseModel):
    name: str
    email: str
    company_name: Optional[str]

class UserInDB(NewUser):
    hash: str = Field(default_factory= lambda: uuid4())
    range = 'DATA'
    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory= lambda: datetime.now())

    def __init__(self, user: NewUser):
        super().__init__(**user.dict())

#...
# Emulating what an end user would send
user = NewUser(name='Example', company_name='example', email='example@example.com')

# This looks probably better
user_in_db = UserInDB(user)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of modifying Pydantic's `__init__`, so I'd suggest either of these two alternative methods.

- `to_db` within `NewUser` means you can create the dict simply by calling `user.to_db()`
- `from_user` within `UserInDB` means you can create the dict by calling `UserInDB.from_user(user)`

Personally I'd go with the first method, but both have their advantages.

Also, note how you can use `Model.parse_obj(Other)` instead of `Model(**Other.dict())`.

```py
class NewUser(BaseModel):
    name: str
    email: str
    company_name: Optional[str] = None

    def to_db(self) -> dict:
        return UserInDB.parse_obj(self).dict(by_alias=True)


class UserInDB(NewUser):
    hash: str = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    db_range = Field('DATA', alias="range") # Avoid mirroring built-in `range`
    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.now)

    @classmethod
    def from_user(cls, user: NewUser) -> dict:
        return cls.parse_obj(user).dict(by_alias=True)


user = NewUser(
    name='Example',
    company_name='example',
    email='example@example.com',
)
 
user_in_db = user.to_db()
# or
user_in_db = UserInDB.from_user(user)

db.create_user(user_in_db)
```